# Should we burninate [dot-notation]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across a question about Prolog to specify a list using *dot notation*.

Apparently there exists a [dot-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dot-notation) tag, and it seems to have a number of questions (~117), but these use dot notation in several different ways:

- the *dot notation* in Prolog to specify a (Lisp) list
- the notation to call a field/method/... from an object, like `foo.bar`
- the dot ([function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition)) operator in functional programming (Haskell)
- *etc.*

In other words the tag is used for several things that all have not that much to do with each other, except that these use a dot.

A very limited introduction to JavaScript, Java, Python, etc. already explains why you need to use a dot. Furthermore there is not that much "*notation*" to it, since usually it is the way to obtain a field, etc. from an object. In that case "dot operator" would make more sense.

The tag also has no excerpt, nor does it has a wiki.

My question is: do we need [dot-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dot-notation)? Perhaps we need to specify first what *dot notation* really is before we can decide what questions belong to this tag.

Comment: Anyway, seriously, WRT your question about the word "notation" vs  something like "operator", this probably refers to the fact that the same operator is written differently in different languages. For instance, where C uses the arrow-notation, C# uses the dot-notation. Things like that.

Comment: @MrLister: but in for instance Prolog *dot notation* is about how you write a list in canonical form. It has almost nothing to do with an *operator*.

Comment: Ehm, I know nothing of Prolog, so I answered the bits in your question that I do know of.

Comment: Makes sense to burninate IMO, it'd be like having an [addition] tag for the concept of adding two things together. I'd like to meet the person who knows how to add two things together in every programming language under the sun.

Comment: It's one term that refers to a lot of different things: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_notation

Comment: @SGR I think it's more like having a `[parenthesis]` tag since the uses can be so disjoint.

Comment: JS specifically distinguishes between [dot notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation) and [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation). They might as well go into [property-accessors] or just [properties], though.

Comment: I've retagged the [only haskell question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28035148/1048572) to [function-composition]. There's nothing special about the dot.

Comment: What about dot-as-concatenation such as in PHP

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring +49/-7. No answers either way.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring +122/-13, 1 (+70/0) answer saying aye, so the tag is set to be burninated.

Answer (score 73):

So, let's run through the [burnination questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191)

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?**

   Not really. The excerpt itself is really vague

   > Any of various syntax conventions for specifying access to objects, object properties, object methods, composite data structures and in other contexts; where a single dot (`.`) is used as a path-step delimiter, or as an operator.

   So if your programming language uses a dot, this tag applies? That's not useful.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

   Yes. This is about programming syntax.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

   No. We don't need a tag for every element of syntax, especially when we consider #4
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

   Not even close. In JS, "dot notation" means referencing the elements of a JS object using a dot (`foo.bar` vs `foo['bar']`). In PHP, it's a concatenation operator (`$foo = 'string' . 'combined';`). Quite a few languages follow the JS notation on objects vs arrays, but with subtle differences (it looks like [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c) has a different bracketed notation from JS).

`Array` means the same thing in all languages. Same with `Object`. But syntax this granular varies from language to language. Having glanced through the list, I would say all of them (that are on-topic) should be retagged to [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax), since that seems to be the goal of these questions

[SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) can manage the burnination, once the community approves

Comment: And the first thing that pops into my (warped) mind when I hear "dot notation" is software release numbers like `12.1.0.2.0`.

Comment: I was thinking IP addresses.

Comment: I was thinking the JS usage.

Comment: I'd say that Array doesn't always mean the same thing, like a php array is very very different from a Java array. But then, if you read php\s documentation on Array it basically says "yo, this is a hash map, not really an array... but like so many things in php it's poorly named and we really don't care" so I'd say that's a bit of an outlier.

Comment: Another exception to "Array means the same thing in all languages" -- R and S use "array" to mean a matrix-like object in `n > 0` dimensions.

Comment: To pile on to arrays not meaning the same thing in every language, Lua's arrays are also tables (= dictionaries = hashes = association lists, whatever) behind the scenes.

Comment: Awk and Tcl have associative arrays, and both have always called them just “arrays”.

Answer (score 7):

## Progress - Completed!!

You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags and:

- flag or close questions that are duplicate/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion based;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value (re-tag), or;
- flag obsolete comments.

Here are some easy links to get you started: [dot-notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dot-notation)

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdot-notation%5D+closed%3Ano) <s>122</s> <s>2</s> 0
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdot-notation%5D+closed%3Ayes) <s>13</s> <s>11</s> 0
- [No answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdot-notation%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) <s>6</s> 0
- [No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdot-notation%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) <s>34</s> <s>2</s> 0

[Review in the Close vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=dot-notation)

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority! If you have specific questions feel free to drop in the [Burnination co-ordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151979/burnination-progress-tragger-for-dot-notation), or in [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), or leave a comment under this post.

---

Thanks to everyone who participated, the tag is now burninated

[image]

Comment: Could you please draw a red free-hand circle on the image to see the important parts-plz

Comment: @kayess the post is a community wiki! Go ahead and add all teh free hand circles you want!