# Organizing Python questions and meanings of 'dot-notation', as applied to Python

Tags: discussion

The term 'dot-notation' *as used in Python* seems to be used for two groups of meanings in Python:

- 1) most are **JavaScript/JSON-inspired coding practices (e.g. expectations that nested object or dict references to undefined (chains of) keys should automatically recursively create all the object attributes/dict keys in the chain, in the manner of defaultdict/autovivification)** ...
- 2) whereas some other mentions are simply "when/should I call a method on an object vs referencing it via attributes, or via a property". Conversely these are existing builtin Python language syntax.

  - [EDIT: per @jpp's answer, **I'm not proposing inventorying all the individual places 'dot notation' is used for builtin Python syntax. Just separating meaning 2) as a group from meaning 1)**]
- What seems to be lost on non-Python programmers is that meaning 1) of "[implementing] dot notation" in Python is largely a foreign thing which the language does not natively implement (yet is well-defined in JS), so unlike JS we have to implement it piecewise ourselves, and that requires that we're clear what the defined behavior(s) are.
- Some questions are only about objects, some only about dicts, some about both, some about the difference between the two. Some are only about old-style/2.x objects and have been obviated by 3.x
- Some questions are about namespaces
- Some questions are about loading/dumping JSON at the same time or in the same code as getting/setting the multiply-nested dicts or objects
- Some uses ignore or break inheritance e.g. by messing with `__getattribute__` or not calling super.
- Moreover, doing this across 3.x and 2.x, and in a performant way, and using builtins where possible, are all considerations.

So the question is: **How can we define and organize the main distinct meanings of 'dot-notation' in Python? and aggregate questions on the first meaning, which is "JS-style automatic getting/setting of nested chains of object attributes/dict keys(/namespaces)". ** Following are some questions **not** to endorse their propositions, just to illustrate that this topic is swimming in duplicates, as a motivation why we should clean this up:

1. First meaning: **"JS-style automatic getting/setting of nested chains of object attributes/dict keys(/namespaces)"** [Note [1]]

   - [What are the differences between Python Dictionaries vs Javascript Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987485/what-are-the-differences-between-python-dictionaries-vs-javascript-objects)
   - [Python dict using dot notation and chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438990/python-dict-using-dot-notation-and-chaining)
   - [How to use a dot “.” to access members of dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352181/how-to-use-a-dot-to-access-members-of-dictionary)
   - [How to use dot notation for (accessing) dict in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279212/how-to-use-dot-notation-for-dict-in-python)  - Checking multiple hierarchical dict keys in a chain, and only creating keys where they do not already exist: [Checking a nested dictionary using a dot notation string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414821/checking-a-nested-dictionary-using-a-dot-notation-string)
   - [Set Python dict items recursively, when given a compound key 'foo.bar.baz'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48729220/set-python-dict-items-recursively-when-given-a-compound-key-foo-bar-baz)
   - [Python recursive setattr()-like function for working with nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17980509/python-recursive-setattr-like-function-for-working-with-nested-dictionaries)
   - [Javascript style dot notation for dictionary keys unpythonic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224026/javascript-style-dot-notation-for-dictionary-keys-unpythonic)
   - [How to create objects on the fly in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575895/how-to-create-objects-on-the-fly-in-python) ; answers include namespaces, tuples using `type`, NamedTuples
   - [Easily dumping variables from/to namespaces/dictionaries in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14903576/easily-dumping-variables-from-to-namespaces-dictionaries-in-python) ; reviews 9 links to other questions addressing dot-access of dynamically-defined variables, but not 'dumping'.
   - [HackerNews article 5/2017: Box: Python dictionaries with recursive dot notation access](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=14273863) covering third-party library [Box](https://github.com/cdgriffith/Box)
2. Second meaning: Questions about native Python syntax for objects, attributes etc.:

   - [What's the Pythonic way to initialize, set and get my custom object's attributes, by name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15281746/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-initialize-set-and-get-my-custom-objects-attributes)
   - [Is the claim that Python methods that use dot notation e.g. `.sort()` don't work on types other than string true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520913/is-the-claim-that-python-methods-that-use-dot-notation-e-g-sort-dont-work)
3. Other unrelated misc mentions in native Python syntax of 'dot notation', referring to methods, module imports and various other things:

   - [Why do some methods use dot notation and others don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703834/why-do-some-methods-use-dot-notation-and-others-dont)
   - [Python importing (module] with dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593981/python-importing-with-dot-notation)
   - A severe misunderstanding stemming from a bad blog: [Do Python methods that use dot notation e.g. `.sort()` work on types other than string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520913/do-python-methods-that-use-dot-notation-e-g-sort-work-on-types-other-than)
   - A misunderstanding from seeing a method call on the float `1.` [What is `1..__truediv__` ? Does Python have a .. ("dot dot") notation syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487811/what-is-python-dot-dot-notation-syntax)
   - [Access Pandas Series item with dot notation like DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383436/access-pandas-series-item-with-dot-notation-like-dataframe)

[NOTE [1]: Strictly, JSON keys are allowed to contain whitespace but Python attribute names aren't. So implementing this via attributes isn't 100% JSON compatible.]

Comment: Is there any reason to not just use the search tools to find what you want to find?

Comment: @Braiam: why are you talking down to me? a) SO's search function is universally acknowledged to be broken b) That's before you get to "dot notation" is not well-defined in Python (although it should be, which is the motivation here) c) I am none of those OPs d) however most of the questions asked are reasonable e) yet there are tons of duplicates of near-duplicates f) and since they weren't ever properly merged, we get garbled answers on this issue going back to 2010 and earlier g) So even if we hypothesize there was a perfect search function, which there isn't, there's still work to be done..

Comment: ...identifying which of these Q&A is canonical and has good answers on 3.x, improving and tagging the canonical ones, and closing all the others as duplicates. So, please join in.

Comment: I was recently working with recursive dicts/defaultdicts. It took me a while to realize that most Python users mentioning "dot notation" in this context simply want JS-style automatic get/set of hierarchies of dict keys and/or object attributes. And that most answers on this are reinventing the wheel. Except for the ones which break inheritance, reach directly into `self.__dict__` (instead of via getattr) or reduce performance, which are plain bad, and should be closed/merged explaining why they're bad. Figuring all that out took me time, and search function won't fix any of that.

Comment: For the couple of people who are downvoting, please make your own suggestions about what if anything can be improved on this topic. Even if you personally don't care that this topic is currently a garbled mess with stale and broken code going back to 2010, it prevents it being a reusable resource for other users.

Comment: @smci: "*How can we define and organize all these distinct meanings of 'dot-notation' in Python?*" I'm not a Python user, so I don't fully understand the technical details of it. But why exactly does SO *need* to do this? What would be improved by having some definition of a concept that Python itself doesn't define? And how would we enforce such a definition?

Comment: @NicolBolas: already addressed above, but the main meaning (in Python) is *"JS-style automatic get/set of hierarchies of dict keys and/or object attributes"*, for which we need to identify canonical targets, merge, then close all the bad/duplicate reaskings. Like I said there is a lot of old 2.x cruft which breaks inheritance or reduces performance, that stuff needs to be closed badly. Conversely for the other meanings (i.e. various places in the existing language syntax where Python uses a '.'), I wasn't suggesting inventorying all of them, per jpp's list. Just disambiguating the first sense

Comment: @NicolBolas: to give a more clear concise answer on the "Why do we need to [in SO Python]?", I revised this to say **"separating meaning 2) (various uses in builtin syntax) as a group from meaning 1) (implementing JS-style)"**. I wasn't suggesting inventorying native syntax uses of the dot under 2).

Comment: Re: *"What would be improved by having some definition of a concept that Python itself doesn't define?"*, getting Python to work recursively the esp. when using JS/JSON(/HTML/XML/YAML) has long been a coding practice in Python (many of the examples I cited are that one same thing). And that meaning is well-defined on the JS/XML/HTML side. Also "enforce" is not necessary (once we merge questions with the first meaning), it really just boils down to the binary "Did you mean hierarchical JS-style? or native builtin Python syntax?"

Answer (score 5):

> How can we define and organize all these distinct meanings of
>   'dot-notation' in Python?

I just don't think it's *possible*. There are just too many questions and uses of dot notation to make aggregating Q&As relevant:

1. **Typos**. Using dot notation incorrectly or where it's not required. Example: in Pandas, confused by usage of `df.some field` instead of correct `df['some field']`.
2. **Methods**. Accessing methods via dot correctly and (usually) forgetting to call the method via parentheses.
3. **Attributes**. Conventions / requirements for valid attribute names.
4. **Functional**. Using `getattr`, `setattr`, etc to access and set attributes functionally via strings.
5. **Enumerating attributes**. Getting a list of all attributes relating to an object.
6. **Using dot instead of `getitem` / `[]` notation**. Improving access "for ease of use", often associated with a desire to create a variable number of variables.

The list goes on and on. I can only deduce there is no way to usefully *aggregate* all these uses of a specific notation. I'd also suggest "by notation" isn't the best way to learn a language. So if someone is actively seeking *all* uses of a particular notation, they are barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: The clear main use is "automatic getting/setting of nested chains of object attributes/dict keys". I didn't suggest making a laundry list of every possible case where Python uses a dot to access things, which is what you compiled here. I meant decoding when people explicitly talk about **implementing "dot-notation" in Python**. That would mean the use case where it is not part of the language syntax. Let me edit the original question to "main meanings" from "all the meanings", which was too expansive.

Comment: Based on what you said I revised the question to scope down to "separating meaning 2) (various use-cases in builtin syntax) as a group from meaning 1) (implementing JS-style)" and remove "all [the meanings]" from the title. I mean someday someone might say "What is the dot notation in `f =1.35`?", and yes we don't need to treat that sort of mention as a legit case either.

Comment: @smci, I know you are well-intentioned, but the problem remains that SO doesn't aim or have *tools* for aggregating answers at this granularity. The kind of things you can try: hard-linking via Related: xyz comments, making an index like [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) which may not go down well with community, or aggressively closing as dups for related but not identical duplicates (also won't go down well). It's tough for diligent organizers like yourself, but SO isn't set up for this.

Comment: With regard to the first meaning, the solution seems a mixture of 'Related:' links and some closing as warranted, similar to what you advise. I care less about the second meaning, it's a pile of years of broken cruft, much of which is invalidated by 3.x, but it seems impossible to reach a community consensus on doing anything to reduce the mess and confusion, so I'm not going to bother. The [CW Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) seems a good way to go, but that one was locked back in 2014 (why? can it be reopened? did people dislike that?)

Comment: @smci, With regards to that locked Q&A, the consensus (usually) is the material lies *between* the tag wiki and Q&A formats. Expanded, indexable tag-wikis with examples of how to ask good questions would be ideal. Sadly, there's no real investment (that I know of) in this area. What you *can* do is put this information on non-affiliated https://sopython.com (with the necessary approvals) and link to it from the tag wiki. This *may* be your best bet, and is better than just writing and sharing a blog as there is *some* community oversight.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions, but https://sopython.com/canon/ is not suitable either, it's only for canonical questions, not for a wiki of duplicate, near-duplicates and bad askings, such as I list here. That's the whole reason I came here to ask. A CW Q&A would have been ideal IMO (excluding plain bad askings), but that doesn't seem to be popular. So that just reduces us to "pick canonicals, close duplicates, add 'Related' link comments on near-duplicates and bad askings, and downvote bad askings. And absolutely not tag-wiki. You might like to edit that into your answer.

Comment: Not suitable for tag-wiki either, even neglecting that a hopelessly undefined language-agnostic [dot-notation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349582/should-we-burninate-dot-notation) got burninated previously. I'm only talking about Python uses here, and ee do not need or want a tag for that.

Comment: @smci there's also https://sopython.com/wiki/ - where we thrash out ideas and such that aren't related to canonicals... for instance we have https://sopython.com/wiki/Common_Gotchas_In_Python

Comment: @JonClements: but are you actually recommending I move this discussion there? It seems a much worse target: no comments or voting, a tiny audience, just community editing and presumably some inevitable revert-warring. It really looks like a terrible target for hosting discussions where people will inevitably have widely differing views. Even here on Meta is better. Better to set out all the different viewpoints to gather some sort of consensus.

Comment: @smci no - I'm not suggesting moving this **discussion** anywhere else... I'm just pointing that out as a potential option to write what is effectively a blog/how-to post for what you're trying to address here... it wouldn't fit well on the SO platform in sense.

Comment: @JonClements: if you're concluding what I'm suggesting won't IYO fit anywhere on SO, isn't that per se a big problem? and in need of an SO solution? I still don't see why CW Q&A's are bad, the regex one looks great. Meanwhile what should I do with this, here on SO/Meta? It feels awfully broken that FGITW duplicate answers are more welcome here than community-minded attempts to clean up the crud and actually make the site welcoming for users with questions like the ones that motivated my post here. I see 7 downvotes here but zero proposed solutions.

Comment: @smci, I'm a big believer in self-answered Q&A. If you believe there is an *on-topic* Q&A on this matter, e.g. along the lines of "why does dot notation do this here, and this something else in this other situation?", then you seem perfectly placed to write such a self-answered Q&A. As such, I can't see a clear on-topic SO question anywhere within your Meta question. Which is likely why few people are interested.

Comment: @jpp: the clear on-topic SO question for the first meaning is *"How to implement JS-style automatic getting/setting of nested chains of object attributes/dict keys (without breaking inheritance or other builtin behavior, and without impacting performance)"*. In all sincerity, how was that not clear? As to the lack of clarity of questions on the second meaning, that's less important than disambiguating and separating them from the first meaning.

Comment: @smci, One sentence itself doesn't make a question. But if you think that there's room to *aggregate* lots of information from various posts, it's possible to construct a canonical self-answered Q&A. Here's a [recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) which was well received by the community. Such a broad Q&A rehashes stuff from lots of posts, sure, but it also coherently brings it altogether. You can hard link all the other posts to the canonical via "Related: How to implement JS-style getting/setting" since dupe-hammering old posts won't go down well.

Comment: @jpp ok but before any of us attempts to write a canonical Q&A, it seemed necessary to first confirm our collective understanding of the main Python senses in which 'dot-notation' is used by Python programmers. Which I believe we did. Next step is to research the *"without breaking inheritance or other builtin behavior, and without impacting performance"* aspect. (For example, is Box library generally agreed to be a good implementation? what are criticisms of it?)

Comment: @smci, `it seemed necessary to first confirm our collective understanding`.. don't get me wrong, but this seems like advice on the technical content of a self-answered Q&A.. Meta isn't the place for this. My advice: post a self-answered Q&A, *then* ask for feedback (especially if you get negative feedback / downvotes). We don't post Q&As "collectively" (unless, partially, if it's a community-wiki, not recommended here), there's no need to do so in this case either.

Comment: @jpp: No, those are your assumptions. I never said this required a self-answered Q&A and I never said it didn't; and I never said I'd be the person to write it. People who post self-answered Q&A are often accused of rephounding or get drive-by downvotes and disparaging comments from people claiming it's not necessary - without making any constructive contribution. And people who post CWs Q&A suffer the same [fate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate) as [the Regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)...

Comment: ...so first I established "These are the separate categories of meaning when Python people use the term 'dot-notation'" (like: there is no third meaning, or fourth meaning. Although I did notice that this isn't strictly "JS-style" since whitespace not allowed in keys). I deem that established, since noone posted anything on-topic or factual to the contrary. However, spending the time and energy to get this far merely attracts +6/-10 votes. Do I have the thick skin to take this one step further, fielding complaints all the way? Why should I? Each person who voted on this could equally do it.

Comment: @smci, So you *don't* want to write a self-answered Q&A? Sorry, I can't help any further then.. and sorry to waste your time. I also think there's no scope on SO for you to contribute what you *want* to contribute. Consider writing a blog, no downvoting there.

Comment: @jpp: Don't misrepresent me. I never said I wouldn't be the person to write it, either. I asked you pointedly why you believe it's reasonable to try to volunteer me to write it, given the grief this Meta post has attracted, plus the grief the [Regex CW Q&A attracted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252868/regex-reference-and-its-fate). Are you saying "Pretend the trolls don't exist, actually getting worthwhile things done on SO may well cause reputation loss, closings and deletions, but that's just the cost of doing something worthwhile?" ...

Comment: ...This on a site which says it's currently introspecting deeply about "being unwelcoming". All the endless drama is too meta. I only come here to learn Python and share my knowledge. Unlike some.Let me restate that more constructively: what are the viable alternatives (IYO) to trying to write a self-answered Q&A? What's wrong with making a decent start by simply closing-as-duplicate and downvoting the (many) obsolete and incorrect answers, the ones which break inheritance or don't work in Python 3? Why is that not an okay approach?

Comment: @smci, Let's not get swayed by downvotes (current or *future*), the aim is to write quality in-scope content, and organize it in a way that facilitates dissemination. [I mean, those other issues are valid, but why not post on *those* Meta posts, not here on this *constructive* Meta.] My proposal / suggestion is for a self-answered Q&A addressing in an in-scope way the problem you have stated. It's *possible* to make it in-scope by constructing an arbitrary problem confusing the aspects you've described. I would write it if I was sufficiently interested; but, alas, I'm not.